# Does changing your GitHub username leave any leftover references to the old name?

Tags: github

I would like to change the username of an old GitHub account which I once used rather than making a brand new one. I don't want to do this unless it leaves no remnants of the old account name. Especially on the profile page.

Answer (score 0):

there are some leftovers, as described [here](https://help.github.com/articles/what-happens-when-i-change-my-username/). The two main drawbacks are below.

1. You will need to manually change your repository references.
2. You will need to change the links to your GitHub profile in social media (or any other site).